# NSNetService/Bonjour discovery only works on iPhone simulator

Tags: ios, bonjour, nsnetservice

I'm working on an iPhone app that requires a basic client/server interaction model. For this I am going to use Bonjour and NSNetService, along with NSNetServiceBrowser to discover others on the same network. I have followed several different guides which more or less have the same sample code.

**Relevant Server Code**

```
...
serverName = [[UIDevice currentDevice] name];
netService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local."
                                             type:@"_myservice._tcp."
                                             name:serverName
                                             port:port];
...
```

The service publishes successfully, i.e. I get the netServiceDidPublish: callback

**Relevant Browser Code**

```
...
browser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
[browser setDelegate:delegate];
[browser searchForServicesOfType:@"_myservice._tcp." 
                        inDomain:@"local."];
...
```

Now the result of all this is interesting:

1. Running on an iPhone, the device can only see its own published NSNetService.
2. Running on 2 iPhones, neither device can see the other's NSNetService.
3. Running on the iPhone Simulator, it will find *all* NSNetServices, including its own.

**Screenshot of iPhone Simulator**

[image]

I'm sort of at a loss here... The simulator is working *exactly* as expected. However on the device it is not, I cannot get 2 different iPhones on the same WiFi to see each other, they only see themselves. Any idea what is going on here?

Comment: You can try a free bonjour browser app from the store to verify its not a connectivity issue in your network, i.e blocked ports (5353).

Comment: I tried a free bonjour browsing app on OSX and iOS. On OSX it discovers all services that I publish. Using the browser app on my phone it cannot find any services. I'm starting to think that I'm missing an extra configuration step to enable discovery on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the router that I'm on had an "SPI Firewall" enabled by default. Turning this off solved the problem.

One thing that I'm still curious about is: How come the requests coming from my Mac, both the iPhone Simulator and a Bonjour Browser, were able to get through this firewall but 3 different iPhones were not?

Comment: Was the simulator and the browser on the Mac itself? In that case, the traffic never leaves the computer (it is broadcast on the "loopback" interface) so it can't be blocked by the router.